# Nginx redirecting proxy_pass server to http://server/index.html

Tags: nginx

I have the following config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;
    location / {
    index index.html;
    }


    server_name command_asdf
    location  /asdf/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001/;
    }
```

When I go to http://server/asdf/index.html everything works fine.

However, if I go to http ://server/asdf/ or http ://server/asdf, they both redirect me to http ://server/index.html instead of http ://server/asdf/index.html

I've spent hours trying to figure out how to instead get it to redirect to the index page on the sub-directory, but sadly had no success.

I have a number of servers I need to use proxy_pass on, however above is the simplest config I can show.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing in your config issues a redirect, so if there's a redirect happening, it's happening in the app you're proxying to.

Comment: You may need to add one or more [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weeks later..Have managed to fix my problem. The solution is:

```
   proxy_redirect    / $request_uri;
```

So when a user accesses foo.com/bar/ it would redirect to foo.com/index.html

This was happening in the 302 redirect the proxy_pass server was issuing.

The above line added to my config will redirect foo.com/bar/ correctly to http://foo.com/bar/ which then loads the index.html page.

Full config:

```
    server_name bar;
    location  /bar/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001/;
    proxy_redirect    / $request_uri;
    }
```

For reference, $request_uri is equal to the location and sub-directory i.e. foo.com/bar/